# Flash object not displaying correctly in ASPX file on FF and Opera

Tags: flash, firefox, height, embed, opera

I have a problem showing up a SWF file (Flash) in an ASP MVC file.

I have problems adjusting the height  to 100%. If this is showed in Firefox or Opera the result is the picture you see below (everything works fine under Chrome and IE).

The code used is the following:

> Welcome
>       
>           body
>           {
>               margin: 0px;
>               overflow: hidden;
>               margin: 0; 
>             padding: 0;
>                 height: 100%;
>             width: 100%;
>           }
>
> ```
>     <div id="slideshow" style="height:100%; width:100%"> 
>
>           <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
>
>                   codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab"
>                   id="name" width="100%" height="100%">
>             <param name="movie" value="../../Assets/PlayAround.swf" />
>             <param name="quality" value="high" />               
>             <embed name="name" src="../../Assets/PlayAround.swf" 
>                 quality="high"                    
>                 width="100%" height="100%" 
>                 type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
>                 pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
>
>             </embed>
>         </object>
>
>     </div> 
>      </body> </html>
> ```

[image]
What am i missing??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For sake of future use:
Firefox and/or Opera seem not to like using swfObject (as i did)! Some has to use a height definition even for the div which is surrounding the SWF embed tag:
[This](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/faq) solved my problem!